# Dealing with CONFIG FAILURE on fresh drive (3ware / LSI RAID)

Tags: raid, 3ware, drive-failure

This is not about DRIVE failure. It's about drive CONFIG failure.

I bought 3 brand new drives for my server, because existing ones have worked for over 4 years and one of them is failing (shows ECC ERROR or DEGRADE). I'm always able to rebuild array with existing drives, but replacing them all is my immediate goal.

I checked specs of these old drives, they are WD2003FYYS, 512 bytes per sector. I thought it would be proper to also acquire 2TB drives with 512n format, so I now have Seagate ST2000NM0055.

**THE PROBLEM**

As seen on the following picture, all three new drives behave exactly the same - 3ware /LSI 9750-8i does not want to detect these properly. Just for kicks I inserted one desktop drive, WD10EZEX with Advanced Format (4K sectors) and it showed status of OK. All 8 drives are in hot-swap bays, so I did a lot of swapping, also tried different bays - no change. Controller's event log does not even show "drive connected" event, as it did for WD10EZEX
[image: Drive config failure]

All Seagates are brand new and have no partition on them (WD10EZEX had one). They work properly in my workstation, connected to eSATA port. CrystalDiskInfo says they're all OK. (lang
[image]

**QUESTION**

Has anybody encountered this type of behavior? How do I deal with this? I've read docs of 9750-8i but didn't find anything about drive config failure, let alone what to do in this case. It's not like I'm a newbie when it comes to various RAIDs and I had 5 different 3ware controllers to this day, but in the case at hand I'm stumped. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when replacing what appeared to be a failing drive on a 3Ware 9650SE controller.

When replacing the drive with a Seagate ST2000DM008-2FR102 drive, I was seeing "config failure", which I couldn't clear.

Eventually, we reseated all the SATA connections, and the problem went away. So it is possible for this to be caused by a slightly loose / dirty SATA cable